# Setting SSL truststore in application.properties for camel-cxf?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, apache-camel, cxf

I have got a CXF client in Camel calling a back end web service on HTTPS.

I can configure the CXF client in a "http-conduit", specify where the trust store is and it works.

Now we are migrating the code to the springboot runtime, I have been trying to find a simpler way to do this, if possible.

At the springboot application level, I can set 2 properties;

```
server_ssl_truststore=my.ts

camel.component.cxf.use-global-ssl-context-parameters=true
```

However, the second property is actually referring to an SSLContextParameters bean on the CamelContext rather than the server settings that I was hoping.

So I basically would be moving the previous configs in a "http-conduit" into an "SSLContextParameters".

Is there something that can bridge the gap so that the cxf component can understand and use the ssl_server_truststore config?